# How do I use the Cryptonote inflation glitch?

Tags: cryptonote

How was the vulnerability mentioned in the article below carried out?

https://getmonero.org/2017/05/17/disclosure-of-a-major-bug-in-cryptonote-based-currencies.html

Can someone give me a step by step walkthrough of how to recreate it ?